# Network blocked FTP?

Tags: networking

Im trying to accessing my ftp server without no luck, at my friends home network. I think it's blocked, but maybe not.

```
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 17 of 100 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 10:03. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> USER lalo.com
< 331 User lalo.com OK. Password required
> PASS (hidden)
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> SYST
< 215 UNIX Type: L8
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
> TYPE A
< 200 TYPE is now ASCII
> PASV
< 227 Entering Passive Mode (193,202,110,181,247,227)
> LIST
```

It connects but then it doesnt list my files and dir/s..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like port 247 (outgoing) is blocked. Try Active FTP mode instead of Passive.

Comment: Nice one that worked!!